# Can't test or get results from added results sources

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, result-source

I am trying to test a results source but strangely I get this error. I searched on the web but I have not idea what I am missing.

[image: Result Source error]

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage the result sources according to the correct process?

You could refer to this official document to check your steps:
[Manage result sources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-result-sources)

There is also an article about the troubleshooting of **Search results aren't returned**, you could also have a look:
[SharePoint Online doesn't return search results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/search/search-results-not-return)

Comment: I am able to add the sources. The problem is in this tenant (the free dev tenant) I get this error in another tenant the same query works completely fine.